# Country total amount in PHP from MYSQL Query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I want to get Country = Total by IPs Adressen in php query already build the basis:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT t.*, gi.cname FROM tasks t LEFT JOIN geoip_all gi WHERE t.ip > geoip_all.iplong_start &&  t.ip < geoip_all.iplong_end", $link);
$county = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "<p>County:\n $county</p> ";
```

I made this query so far only it don't work.

```
SELECT t.*, gi.cname FROM tasks t LEFT JOIN geoip_all gi WHERE t.ip > geoip_all.iplong_start &&  t.ip < geoip_all.iplong_end
```

Error message from query run in phpmyadmin:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN geoip_all.cname LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

`geoip_all.cname` = Country name
`geoip_all.iplong_start` = start of the ip ranges
`geoip_all.iplong_end` = start of the ip ranges
`task.ip` = IP from the visitor in the colunm is this the value : 636736027

Screenshots of the database:

geoip_all table: 
http://screencloud.net/v/5CgY

task.ip: http://screencloud.net/v/6B0L

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are possibly mixing up ANSI 89 and 92 syntax in your statement

```
SELECT 
    t.*, 
    gi.cname 
FROM 
    tasks t 
        LEFT JOIN geoip_all gi 
            on t.ip > gi.iplong_start 
            and  t.ip < gi.iplong_end
```

I have changed your `where` to an `on` statement. You are able to still add an actual `where` clause on the bottom of this statement though.

You might also do well to have a read of [this in depth article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) I put together on how to get data from multiple tables. It covers off joins, inner and outer, aggregates and a bunch more.

Comment: Get this error:  #1054 - Unknown column 'geoip_all.iplong_start' in 'on clause'

Comment: @RaoulCode Made an edit to the code. I guess if we are aliasing the tables, we should be using the alias itself when referencing them... :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SELECT t.*, gi.cname FROM tasks t LEFT JOIN geoip_all gi WHERE t.ip > geoip_all.iplong_start &&  t.ip < geoip_all.iplong_end
```

To:

```
SELECT t.*, gi.cname FROM tasks AS t LEFT JOIN geoip_all AS gi WHERE t.ip > geoip_all.iplong_start &&  t.ip < geoip_all.iplong_end;
```

I believe you're missing the AS statements to query your tables AS something.

Comment: You don't need to as `as` when making an alias. It's nice and readable, but not a syntax thing.

Comment: Try changing your geoip_all.iplong_start and geoip_all.iplong_end to gi.iplong_start and gi.iplong_end

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use inclusive comparison (e.g. match when IP address is `1.0.0.0`)

```sql
SELECT t.*, gi.cname
FROM tasks t
LEFT JOIN geoip_all gi ON (t.ip BETWEEN gi.iplong_start AND gi.iplong_end)
```

It's not clear from your screenshot if the IP ranges in `geoip_all` can overlap. If so, the above query may return multiple rows for one task.

---

If you want the number of tasks in each country (based on IP address), you'd be better off using `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`. Something like,

```sql
SELECT gi.cname, COUNT(*)
FROM tasks t
LEFT JOIN geoip_all gi ON (t.ip BETWEEN gi.iplong_start AND gi.iplong_end)
GROUP BY 1
```

Again, this query returns accurate results only if the IP ranges are guaranteed to not overlap.